# What does 'dissociated realities' mean?

Tags: meaning

Sorry my main language is not english. What does *dissociated realities* mean? I came across this phrase a couple of times when I read some articles and such. But, I don't think I really understand what that phrase means.

Comment: Could you please link the source of this phrase (and,  perhaps, show us your research)?

Comment: [**Dissociative Reality** and Dissociative Being in Therapy for Post traumatic Patients](https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/25841110/)

Comment: English (always with a capital). But it doesn’t seem English to me. More technobabble. Please finish the [Tour], provide context to phrases and consider whether SE English Language Learners might be more appropriate.